# How can I get the value of a cell that is colored red?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very simple script that loops through all cells and checks to see if they are red.  If any cell is red, I want to capture the value of the cell, in whatever row it is and ColumnB.  For some reason my code below will find the correct red cells, but it won't capture the value of the cell.  I must be missing something simple here, but I don't know what it is.

Basically, 'ValueRed' is always "".

```
For i = 1 To R.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To R.Columns.Count
         If Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
             Set ValueRed = Cells(i, 2)
             finalsetred = "Delete: " & ValueRed
         End If
    Next
Next
```

I'd definitely appreciate some help with this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why the two loops when you only reference column 2?

Comment: I know, I know.  I'm running another process to check all rows and all columns for yellow cells.  That part works fine, and it's a lot more complex then the reds issue.  I don't know what I'm missing here.  It loops into the red cells bu tit just doesn't pick up the values of those red cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the datatype for `ValueRed`?

If its string for example just use `ValueRed = Cells(i, 2)`, drop the `Set`

`Set` is required with objects.

---

```
For i = 1 To R.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To R.Columns.Count
         If Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
             ValueRed = Cells(i, 2)
             finalsetred = "Delete: " & ValueRed
         End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks!  It was actually this: ValueRed = Cells(i, 3).Value
ColumnB was blank, I really wanted to check ColumnC for the value.  
Damn!!  I'm going home early today!!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're after here.
You want to check all the cells, and if they're red then to set the value of the column B cell in that row to say "Delete: " & red cell value?

This code would work (assuming max one red cell per row:)

```
For i = 1 To R.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To R.Columns.Count
         If Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
             Cells(i, 2) = "Delete: " & cells(i,j)
         End If
    Next
Next
```

Though to be more robust i'd expect multiple reds per row.

```
Dim strReds As String
For i = 1 To R.Rows.Count
    strReds = vbNullString
    For j = 1 To R.Columns.Count
        If Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            If strReds = vbNullString Then
                strReds = "Delete: " & Cells(i, j)
            Else
                strReds = strReds & ", " & Cells(i, j)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Cells(i, 2) = strReds
Next
```